# Rails 5 break validating chain when a validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my user model I have a validation rule like:

```
validates :email, presence: true, my_email_format: true, uniqueness: true
```

I want to break the chain when any validation is failed, such as when the email format is wrong (my_email_format failed), the uniqueness validation will not run.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want that but if you want to, you can split the `validates` into multiple lines

```
validates :email, presence: true
validates :email, my_email_format: true, if: ->{errors[:email].blank?}
validates :email, uniqueness: true, if: ->{errors[:email].blank?}
```

Comment: Thnx, it can solve my problem. I think that there is no need to fetch the record in database if the email format is wrong , because it does absolutely not exist.

Comment: Yeah, but your adding complexity for micro efficiency. Unless your doing thousands of validations at once, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create `before_validation` hook. Throw `:abort` message when you want to break the validation chain.

For example:

```
before_validation :validate_email, on: :create

...

def validate_email
  if (email_is_invalid)
    errors.add(:base, error_message)
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```